# Disable ec2 metadata service from cloud-init

Tags: virtualbox, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I have an AWS EC2 image that I converted to VirtualBox and running locally. It works great, except I cannot figure out how to disable to calls out to the AWS metadata services on boot:

```
2015-09-25 19:29:29,932 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id' failed [50/120s]: request error [(<urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool object at 0x7fb78650efd0>, 'Connection to 169.254.169.254 timed out. (connect timeout=50.0)')]
2015-09-25 19:30:20,987 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id' failed [101/120s]: request error [(<urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool object at 0x7fb78652cb90>, 'Connection to 169.254.169.254 timed out. (connect timeout=50.0)')]
2015-09-25 19:30:39,011 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id' failed [119/120s]: request error [(<urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool object at 0x7fb78650ee10>, 'Connection to 169.254.169.254 timed out. (connect timeout=17.0)')]
2015-09-25 19:30:40,015 - DataSourceEc2.py[CRITICAL]: Giving up on md from ['http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id'] after 120 seconds
2015-09-25 19:31:43,509 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed to fetch password from virtual router 192.168.128.1
```

Where in cloud-init can I disable these? These calls time out eventually, but cause the boot of the VirtualBox image to take over 2 minutes.

Comment: What is the output from `cat /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use a cloud-image with virtualbox, I'd suggest the `.vmdk` that Canonical produces instead of the ec2 ami.  It's already set up to use the [no-cloud data source](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/nocloud.html) and my version of virtualbox already works with a .vmdk natively (or converts transparently, I am not really sure).

For detailed instructions, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797462/problem-with-ubuntu-cloud-image-16-04-on-virtualbox) has more.

Answer (score 2):

For a one-off virtualbox @ching's answer is fine.  However, if you are making a template and you need cloud-init to configure things for you then the "correct" way to do this is to create an override file in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/`. Files in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/` will override the values in `/etc/cloud.cfg`.

Example:

Value in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`

```
datasource_list: [ Ec2, None ]
```

New file `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99_overrides.cfg`

```
datasource_list: [ None ]
```

You can add other providers here instead of Ec2 - VMware, ConfigDrive, etc which can be really handy for provisioning things like you would with the EC2 metadata.

See: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources.html

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl disable cloud-config.service
systemctl disable cloud-final.service 
systemctl disable cloud-init.service 
systemctl disable cloud-init-local.service
```