# Problem with Ubuntu cloud image 16.04 on VirtualBox

Tags: boot, virtualbox, password, cloud-init

I was trying to use Ubuntu 16.04 cloud image xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.vmdk  [downloaded from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/ ] on VirtualBox but facing two problems:

1. Booting the VM stops indefinitely following the message "...random: nonblocking pool is initialized ".  The same VM image on Vmware workstation takes to the the 'ubuntu login' successfully.
2. Since the cloud image doesn't have ubuntu password, I tried to pass this with  "init=/usr/lib/cloud-init/uncloud-init  ds=nocloud ubuntu-pass=ubuntu" as described in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/Images/KVMKernelOptions, but it doesn't seem to work as the login doesn't accept the password.

Thanks for any help regarding the issues.

Comment: I can not login neither, waiting for answers

Answer (score 2):

### Instead of what you are doing

As your question is old, these may be better ways to start 16.04 virtual machines.

- [multipass](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/beta-release-multipass/2696) - launch ubuntu images really easily, [even testing cloud-init config](https://powersj.github.io/post/cloud-init-multipass/) in the process
- [uvt-kvm](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cloud-images-and-uvtool.html) - more developer centric ubuntu launch model

### Answer to your Question

As you asked specifically about virtualbox, as of the current writing, I see the following issues in your current procedure:

1. You need to enable a serial port on your virtual box machine.  In the UI, it's a matter of checking the 'serial port' box.  The `vboxmanage` cli also has a way to do this.
2. I see you are modifying the kernel command line, but I don't know [how to do that in virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/pipermail/vbox-dev/2011-July/009908.html), so instead, I attach an .iso with the right cloud config following a modification of [this procedure](https://gist.github.com/smoser/6066204).

### Virtualbox cloud-image procedure

This is modified from the [reference procedure](https://gist.github.com/smoser/6066204), but worked for me

- Download the latest 16.04 .vmdk file
- Create the seed.iso with `#cloud-config` (see below)
- Create a virtualbox VM

  - **disk**: point to ubuntu-16.04.vmdk download
  - **cdrom**: seed.iso
  - **enable serial port**
- Upon boot, I can login.

### Creating a seed.iso

```
## create user-data file and a iso file with that user-data on it.
$ seed_iso="my-seed.iso"
$ cat > my-user-data <<EOF
#cloud-config
password: passw0rd
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
EOF
$ cloud-localds "$seed_iso" my-user-data
```

### References

- https://askubuntu.com/a/921830/7056
- https://gist.github.com/smoser/6066204